# Enable HTTPS for Heroku application

Tags: heroku, production

Our main domain is hosted in Heroku. One of our subdomain is hosted in Godaddy. We bought DNS from Godaddy. And we bought one SSL from Godady. While we follow enable HTTPS document in Godaddy, HTTPS enabled for sub domain (which is hosted in Godaddy) but I want to enable HTTPS for main domain (which is hosted in Heroku) While I try the below

```
heroku certs:add combined.crt server.key
Resolving trust chain... done
Adding SSL certificate to ⬢ playgaffer-production-webapp... !
 ▸    You need to be running on either Hobby or Professional dynos to be able to use SNI SSL.
```

got this message. While I check with Heroku found

```
The minimum requirement is to use a Hobby tier dyno which has a cost of $7/month.
```

1. Am I can't use the ssl we bought in Godaddy for main domain?
2. Can I Enable HTTPS freely (which is hosted in Heroku)

Answer (score 3):

As it says this is a requirement from Heroku. Your app must be running under "Hobby" or "Professional" plans.

This happened to me today while configuring a free "letsencrypt" SSL certificate ... at least it was free :-\

BTW: Here's a manual of how to create and configure a free SSL certificate with letsencrypt and heroku (although it has the requirements we mention up) https://medium.com/@franxyzxyz/setting-up-free-https-with-heroku-ssl-and-lets-encrypt-80cf6eac108e